# parsing json with different schema with Play json

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I've got to parse a list of Json messages. I am using Play Json

All messages have similar structure, and at high level may be represented as

```
case class JMessage(
  event: String,
  messageType: String,
  data: JsValue // variable data structure
)
```

`data` may hold entries of different types - Double, String, Int, so I cant go with a Map.

Currently there are at least three various types of the data. The structure of `data` may be identified by `messageType`.

So far I've created three case classes each representing the structure of `data`.  As well as implicit `Reads` for them. And the 4th one that is a case class for result with some `Option`-al fields. So basically I need to map various json messages to some output format.

The approach I'm currently using is:

```
messages.map(Json.parse(_)).(_.as[JMessage]).map {
  elem => {
    if (elem.messageType == "event") {
      Some(parseMessageOfTypeEvent(elem.data))
    } 
      Some(..)
    } else {
      None
  }
}
.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

The `parseMessageOfType%type%` functions are basically `(v: type) => JsValue`.

So after all I have 4 case classes and 3 functions for parsing.  It works, but it is ugly.

Is there a more beautiful Scala way to it?

Comment: Having a case classe for each schema makes perfect sense. Overall your method looks fine (just that you might be able to improve it a bit with pattern matching). If you are looking for alternative JSON libraries in Scala, take a look at [circe](https://github.com/circe/circe). You can parse an ADT using a discriminator field (which seems to fit your use case if you define the `JMessage` as a trait and then extend it with those 3 case classes).

Comment: I've explored circe for a little and managed to implement same approach using ADT, the major flaw of the approach is - the circe will let messages with unwanted attributes through unless you construct Decoder manually.
Assume data should be `{x: Int, y: Int}`, but circe will accept anything that has `{x: Int, y: Int, Whatever: Else}`. It will only extract x & y though.